# Mongoose find and update nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find and update a sub document under another sub document. I am not getting the result as I expect.  This is what I currently have setup:

```
const SiteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
domain: { type: String, required: true },
keywords: [],
campaigns: [
    {
        campaign: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Campaign",
        },
        responses: [
            {
                message: { type: String },
                asking_fee: { type: Number },
                date: { type: Date },
            },
        ],
    }],
})
```

I would like to find and edit a particular response. Here is the code I have now. I am new to mongoose and MongoDB.

```
const site = await Site.findOneAndUpdate({
    "campaigns.responses._id": responseId, // will it fetch the response ?
  }, {
     $set: {   // I am struggling with the following
         "campaigns.$.responses.message": message,  
        "campaigns.$.responses.asking_price": asking_price,
        "campaigns.$.responses.date": date,
        },
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `campaigns.campaign` id then you have to use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$set` to update `campaigns` field, `$map` to iterate loop of `campaigns` array, `$map` to iterate loop of `campaigns.responses` array and check condition if `responseId` match then return updateFields otherwise return old fields and merge with current object using `$mergeObjects`

```
let responseId = 1;
let updateFields = {
  message: "new message",
  asking_fee: 10,
  date: new Date()
};
const site = await Site.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "campaigns.responses._id": responseId },
  [{
    $set: {
      campaigns: {
        $map: {
          input: "$campaigns",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                responses: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$this.responses",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this",
                        {
                          $cond: [
                            { $eq: ["$$this._id", responseId] },
                            updateFields,
                            "$$this"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6dxLxSsO_Bi)

---

Second option if you have `campaigns.campaign` id then you can use `$[<identifier>]` [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html),

```
let campaign = 1;
let responseId = 1;
let updateFields = {
  message: "new message",
  asking_fee: 10,
  date: new Date()
};
const site = await Site.findOneAndUpdate({
  "campaigns.campaign": campaign,
  "campaigns.responses._id": responseId
},
{
  $set: {
    "campaigns.$[parent].responses.$[child]": updateFields
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    { "child._id": responseId },
    { "parent.campaign": campaign }
  ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bFCfPrVjrTr)

Comment: I have the campaign Id and used the second option. It works. Thanks a lot.